# React Native 0.60 connection to development server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gradle

(I'm almost a newbie in React Native development) today I have started a new project in React Native 0.60 (`react-native init MyApp`).

After that I typed : `react-native run-android` to check if everything worked.

After the bundle process is finished 
[image]
I can finally get my welcome screen in my connected devices

[image]

But, if I try to reload the app from my devices I get this error:

[image]

How could I address this error ?

EDIT: Thank you for your answers, anyway, I have tried all solutions you suggest but I still get the same problem. I also noticed that when i run `react-native run-android` Metro Bundler (open in a new cli window) seems to start but it suddenly disappear. I think the problem could be with the message '**Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0**'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

react-native run-android not working in new react-native version

> 0.60

now you can use

```
 react-native start
```

OR

```
 npm start
```

both command is work

Comment: I tried it , but the execution of script seems to be stucked in  'loading dependency graph, done' (example : https://imgur.com/3bs973E)

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following two commands and then can start the react native again.

```
 - adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
 - killall node
```

Then you can run the following the command.

```
react-native start
```

Now you can run your application again.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your phone to the server, follow the below steps:
[For detailed help follow this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device]

**1.** Open the developer menu on phone.

**2.** Open 'Debug server host & port for device'.

**3.** Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (eg. 10.0.1.1:8081). If you have connected over wifi then this will be your computers ip address. (If you are running in your computer I think instead of ip address it would be 'localhost:8081')

**4.** Go back to the Dev menu and select reload.

Hope it would help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run adb reverse in the Android Studio terminal so your device can connect to the server. Open Android Studio and click on the terminal button at the bottom. In the terminal, and with your device connected to your computer, enter the command `adb devices`. This will list the name of the connected Android device. Copy that name. Then enter this command `adb -s <device name> reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`. When you run that command replace `<device name>` with the name of your device you copied from the other command.

[Here is a link to an explanation in the React Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#connecting-to-the-development-server-1)